# apache reverse proxy with socket communication

Tags: apache, sockets, https, reverse-proxy

[image: architecture]

## Use case:

I have a use case in which my server is compatible with http but not with https. client is able to communicate with server in http correctly. To make the communication between client and server use https, I setup apache reverse proxy server which receives request in https and sends request in http to server and get response from server in http and sends it back to client in https.

## Issue:

I only have one issue my client send request to server with a port on which it is listening for callback. This callback works in http(direct client communication with server) but not in https(client passing through apache to server). I believe this is because server tries to open socket on client specified port on apache machine which is not listening for that port.

## Question:

I want to verify that it is not possible to create socket connection from server to client through apache because apache is not aware which socket request from server is for which client.